# Optional arguments and Descriptor instance

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-descriptors

I'm using descriptors (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#customized-names)), so each value gets automatically converted to float.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

class ToFloat:

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        value = getattr(obj, self.private_name)
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, float(value))

@dataclass
class Coordinates:
   lon: float = ToFloat() 
   lat: float = ToFloat()
   val: float = ToFloat() 

c = Coordinates(lon=1 , lat=2, val=3)
# 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

However, how can I make these fields optional? (with or without `@dataclass`).

This does not work:

```
c = Coordinates()
# TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: lat, long, val
```

Comment: Probably quite complicated to combine `Field` with a custom descriptor. You may be interested in [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/).

Comment: Define your own `__init__` method for `Coordinates`, with optional arguments. It will override the default created by `@dataclass`.

Comment: The descriptors are *class* attributes, not instance attributes.

Comment: @alexis , so, perhaps it is better to completely remove the `@dataclass` then , right?

Comment: I guess you can keep the `@dataclass` if you want. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the one way I showed of using it with dataclasses.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple and straightforward solution that seems to work. I'm using PyCharm and also it doesn't seem to show any type warnings etc. when I leave out the field names to the `__init__` method.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


class ToFloat:

    def __init__(self, default_value=None):
        self.default = default_value

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        value = getattr(obj, self.private_name)
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if isinstance(value, ToFloat):
            setattr(obj, self.private_name, self.default)
        else:
            setattr(obj, self.private_name, float(value))


@dataclass
class Coordinates:
    lon: float = field(default=ToFloat(0.0))
    lat: float = field(default=ToFloat(0.1))
    val: float = field(default=ToFloat(0.2))


c = Coordinates(lon=1, lat=2, val=3)
print(c)
# Coordinates(lon=1.0, lat=2.0, val=3.0)

c = Coordinates()
print(c)
# Coordinates(lon=0.0, lat=0.1, val=0.2)
```

And if you want to simplify the logic under `__set__` (which right now does an `isinstance` check each time), you can simply have it like this:

```py
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, float(value))

    def __float__(self):
        return self.default
```

Comment: This is really clever. The only issue I can see is that MyPy -- which does stricter type-checking than PyCharm -- isn't a fan of annotating `lon`, `lat`, and `value` with `float` when the `default` value of the `field` doesn't return a `float`. You can get around that by using `typing.cast`: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=d102d2150eaf4dff0424ad18fc572ec7

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would to remove the type hints:

```
@dataclass
class Coordinates:
   lon = ToFloat() 
   lat = ToFloat()
   val = ToFloat()

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lon = kwargs.pop("lon", None)
        self.lat = kwargs.pop("lat", None)
        self.val = kwargs.pop("val", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

That would require some adaptiations to the descriptor though which will need to handle `None` or some other "default" value.

```
class ToFloat:
    # ...
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        value = value if value is None else float(value)
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)
```

This, of course, has no more `dataclass` functionality unless you have other fields around.

You might want to consider another package, [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), which brings your needs pretty much ootb:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Coordinates(BaseModel):
    lon: float = None
    lat: float = None
    val: float = None
 
c = Coordinates()
c.lon
# None
c = Coordinates(lon=5)
c.lon
# 5.0
c
# Coordinates(lon=5.0, lat=None, val=None)
Coordinates(lon=5) == Coordinates(lon="5")
# True
```

Comment: +1, though it's perhaps worth noting that the auto-generated `__init__` method isn't the *only* thing the `dataclass` decorator does for you — the auto-generated `__eq__` and `__repr__` methods area also pretty useful.

Comment: True, but for they both won't use the 3 (non) fields here, so they will be pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated, `dataclasses` and descriptors don't really play well together. The "classic" way of doing what you're trying to do would be to write something like this:

```
class ToFloat:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        value = getattr(obj, self.private_name)
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, float(value))


class Coordinates:
    lon = ToFloat() 
    lat = ToFloat()
    val = ToFloat()
    
    def __init__(self, lon, lat, val):
        self.lon = lon
        self.lat = lat
        self.val = val
    
c = Coordinates(lon=1 , lat=2, val=3)
# 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

If you want to add type hints, MyPy will understand what you're doing [just fine](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=02ecb50bc2e54cae6bb45ae601557a5e) as long as you add a return type to the `__get__` method of `ToFloat`:

```
class ToFloat:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None) -> float:
        value = getattr(obj, self.private_name)
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, float(value))


class Coordinates:
    lon = ToFloat() 
    lat = ToFloat()
    val = ToFloat()
    
    def __init__(self, lon, lat, val):
        self.lon = lon
        self.lat = lat
        self.val = val
    
c = Coordinates(lon=1 , lat=2, val=3)
reveal_type(c.lon)
# Revealed type is float
```

The disadvantage of writing classes this way, however, is that you have to define a fairly boilerplate `__init__` method for any class you define like this. If you want `dataclass`-y `__repr__`, `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods, you'll have to define those as well.

One solution is to use a third-party library such as `attrs` or `pydantic`. However, there's also nothing to stop you writing your own decorator to reduce boilerplate:

```
from typing import get_type_hints, Generic, TypeVar
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

T = TypeVar('T')

class AbstractValidator(Generic[T], metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None) -> T:
        value = getattr(obj, self.private_name)
        return value

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def validate(input_val) -> T: ...

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, self.validate(value))


def validated_dataclass(cls):
    fields = [k for k, v in cls.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, AbstractValidator)]
    
    init = f'def __init__(self, {", ".join(fields)}):\n'
    init += '\n'.join(f'   self.{field} = {field}' for field in fields)
    namespace = {}
    exec(init, globals(), namespace)
    cls.__init__ = namespace['__init__']
    return cls
    

class ToFloat(AbstractValidator[float]):
    @staticmethod
    def validate(input_val) -> float:
        return float(input_val)


@validated_dataclass
class Coordinates:
    lon = ToFloat() 
    lat = ToFloat()
    val = ToFloat()
    

c = Coordinates(lon=1 , lat=2, val=3) # works fine
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you know exactly how your code works, whereas there is a *lot* of magic going on in libraries like pydantic, some of which you may not need, but may [slow your code down](https://threeofwands.com/why-i-use-attrs-instead-of-pydantic/) unnecessarily. The disadvantage is that it takes a little bit of work to set up — but once you've set it up, it's extremely  extensible. It would be very easy to create `ToStr` or `RaisesIfLessThan10` validators inheriting from `AbstractValidator`, if you wanted to. You could also add options to auto-generate `__repr__`/`__eq__`/`__hash__` methods, like with `dataclasses`, if you like.

Another disadvantage is that this kind of dynamic code generation is impossible for Mypy to work out (`dataclasses` are special-cased by type-checkers). As it is, MyPy will raise an error telling you that `Coordinates.__init__` received unexpected arguments. You can solve this by rewriting rewriting `Coordinates` like so — it reintroduces a little boilerplate, but it's still less boilerplate than the "classic" solution, and mypy now understands the signature of the auto-generated `__init__` method that you're replacing the stub with in the `validated_dataclass` decorator.

```
@validated_dataclass
class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self, lon, lat, val) -> None: ...
    
    lon = ToFloat() 
    lat = ToFloat()
    val = ToFloat()
```